# Determining that the singularity of a differential equation is a pole only.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

The equation is:
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\mathrm{d}z} = w-w^2 $$
where $w(z)$ is a complex function. To solve, I separated variables and then used partial fraction decomposition to obtain:
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}w}{w(1-w)} =\mathrm{d}z $$
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}w}{w}-\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{1-w}=\mathrm{d}z  $$
Integrating both sides and combining $\ln$ terms, we have:
$$ \frac{w}{1-w}=z-z_0 $$
$$ w = \frac{Ce^z}{1+Ce^z} \quad\quad\text{where}\quad C=e^{-z_0} $$
Now my confusion is how to use this to solution to prove all the singularities are poles. The singularities occur at
$$ 1+Ce^z=0 \implies Ce^z=-1 =e^{z-z_0} = -1   $$
$$ \implies z-z_0 = (2k+1)\pi i $$
So then it would be an essential singularity not a pole - right?
Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think you have an essential singularity?

Comment: because regardless of what $z_0$ is there will be infinitely many of them?

Comment: The function $1/\sin(z)$ has infinitely many poles. It has an essential singularity only at infinity.